# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 41420841 bytes)

Tags: php, cakephp, memory, upload

The CakePHP app that I'm working on allows the upload of PDF files, and using FPDF, merges those PDFs together. This is the first time that I've seen this issue, but it seems that really large PDFs are breaking they system:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 41420841 bytes)`

I've already changed the **php.ini** to allow 512M and used `ini_set('memory_limit','512M');`, but neither seem to be making a difference.

Any thoughts on how to track down the memory limit?

Comment: Have you checked for an "endless" loop?

Comment: Try to disable debug within that action. And check the queries within that action, maybe one(or more) are containing a lot of other models.

Comment: Try showing some code - or a stacktrace. As is your question is too vague to answer and _is_ a duplicate of the questino linked by @IOIOMAD.